# Visualize IoT Data With Kaa and MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, kaa, mongodb-compass

I followed this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/visualize-iot-data-with-kaa-and-mongodb-compass but I have a problem at the "Visualizing Logs in MongoDB Compass" step. I can't be succesful to connect to the host. Message error is

> MongoDB not running on the provided host and port

Answer (score 1):

To resolve I set virtual box in bridge network mode

Answer (score 0):

Open `mongod.conf` from KAA server using this command:

```
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment out this line:

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Restart the MongoDB service using:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Then, try to connect from MongoDB Compass using host address and port number.